# Expandable Dojo Grid

Tags: dojox.grid

Is it possible to use a DojoX Grid to realize an expandable Grid?

I have a data structure Person with attributes 'Name', 'Prename' and an arbitrary number of addresses. I would like to have a grid that displays the 'Name' and 'Prename' of the Persons. Additionally there should be a 'plus' icon at the left of every row. When clicking on that icon the row should be expanded. I.e. a 'div' with all the addresses of the selected person should be displayed below the selected row.

Can this be realized using the DojoX DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Could a dojox.grid.TreeGrid work for you?

Here's an overview: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/TreeGrid.html

There are some examples at the bottom of this page of grid tests: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/